# Problem using boost::object_pool boost version 1.56 with visual studio 2019

Tags: c++, boost, visual-studio-2019, visual-studio-2008-sp1

I am trying to convert boost::object_pool usage on my old project to new visual studio 2019 project, I am using boost version 1.56

ObjectPool.h

```
class BOOST_OBJECT_POOL_CHECKER
{
  boost::object_pool< T > m_sObjectPool;
  
  template <class Arg1>
  T* contruct(Arg1& sArg1)
  {
     T* temp = m_sObjectPool.construct(sArg1);
     return temp;
  }
}
```

MaterialServer.h

```
class MaterialServer
{
   MaterialServer(dword serviceType, std::string path);
   Material* NEW_MATERIAL();
}
```

Material.h

```
class Material
{
  BOOST_OBJECT_POOL_CHECKER<Material> m_poolMATERIAL;

  Material(MaterialServer* pMatServer);
  
}
```

Material.cpp

```
Material* MaterialServer::NEW_MATERIAL()
{
   //Material* returnMaterial = m_poolMATERIAL.construct(this); << error on vs2019, not correct parameter
   Material* returnMaterial = m_poolMATERIAL.construct(*this);
}
```

got first error

```
boost_1_56\boost\pool\detail\pool_construct_simple.ipp(19,1): error C2664: 'Material::Material(MaterialServer*)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'const T0' to 'MaterialServer *'
ObjectPool.h(68): message : see reference to function template instantiation 'Material *boost::object_pool<T,boost::default_user_allocator_new_delete>::construct<Arg1>(const T0 &)' being compiled
        with
        [
            T=Material,
            Arg1=MaterialServer,
            T0=MaterialServer
        ]
```

should I need upgrade boost version? because previously this code compiled fine on vs2008, but not compiled on vs2019, this c++11 standard so confusing for me

can I get explanation this behavior?

Comment: Before even reading. Please upgrade boost. It makes no sense to use a version from 2015 with a much more recent compiler. Quite obviously, the compiler is not on the list of supported platforms

Comment: [_"Your code was missing some semicolons here and there, and the union was missing member names."_](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66123557/85371) - this is a rather annoying pattern in your questions, @navirius. If you care to post a link to your actual code base (github?) I would rather look at it as it really is... Of course, it might just be too much work, but I guess it'll be quicker than going at these one by one and getting a distorted picture of of the code each time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Frankly, this code cannot have compiled under any compiler.

> ***Note**: I'm ignoring numerous typos, omitted semi-colons, omitted `template` declarators, typedefs and [access specifiers](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/access) to focus on the real issues.*

You're passing `*this` which is `Material&`. However, the `contruct` [sic] function takes a `MaterialServer*`.

So, in fact, the commented line was closer, and makes sense IFF it were a member of `MaterialServer`, not `Material`.

It would make a lot more sense, logically, for the material server to "create new materials", anyways, and almost works:

```
class Material {
  public:
    Material(MaterialServer* pMatServer);
};

class MaterialServer {
    BOOST_OBJECT_POOL_CHECKER<Material> m_poolMATERIAL;

  public:
    MaterialServer(dword serviceType, std::string path);
    Material* NEW_MATERIAL();
};

Material* MaterialServer::NEW_MATERIAL()
{
    Material* returnMaterial = m_poolMATERIAL.construct(this);
    return returnMaterial;
}
```

I say /almost/ because `construct` takes its argument by mutable reference. That won't compile here (`this` is NOT a mutable lvalue).

So, fixing that:

```
template <typename Arg1> T* construct(Arg1 sArg1) {
    return m_sObjectPool.construct(sArg1);
}
```

Or, more generically:

```
template <typename... Arg> T* construct(Arg&&... sArg) {
    return m_sObjectPool.construct(std::forward<Arg>(sArg)...);
}
```

We get "compiling code". We can't link it (the constructors aren't defined).

Adding some more imagined code:

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f42435503e5bfa56)**

```
#include <boost/pool/object_pool.hpp>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <atomic>

using dword = uint32_t;

template <typename T> class BOOST_OBJECT_POOL_CHECKER {
    boost::object_pool<T> m_sObjectPool;

  public:
    template <typename... Arg> T* construct(Arg&&... sArg)
    {
        return m_sObjectPool.construct(std::forward<Arg>(sArg)...);
    }
};

class MaterialServer; // forward declare

class Material {
  public:
    Material(MaterialServer* pMatServer);
};

class MaterialServer {
    BOOST_OBJECT_POOL_CHECKER<Material> m_poolMATERIAL;

    dword _serviceType;
    std::string _path;

  public:
    MaterialServer(dword serviceType, std::string path)
        : _serviceType(serviceType)
        , _path(path)
    {
    }

    Material* NEW_MATERIAL();

    dword getServiceType() const { return _serviceType; }
    std::string_view getPath() const { return _path; }
};

Material* MaterialServer::NEW_MATERIAL()
{
    Material* returnMaterial = m_poolMATERIAL.construct(this);
    return returnMaterial;
}

Material::Material(MaterialServer* pMatServer)
{
    static std::atomic_int id{0};
    std::cout << "Material " << id++ << " from server ("
              << pMatServer->getServiceType() << ", "
              << std::quoted(pMatServer->getPath()) << ")\n";
}

int main() {
    MaterialServer a(123, "Material/a/resource");
    MaterialServer b(234, "Material/b/resource");

    a.NEW_MATERIAL();
    a.NEW_MATERIAL();
    b.NEW_MATERIAL();
    a.NEW_MATERIAL();
}
```

Prints

```
Material 0 from server (123, "Material/a/resource")
Material 1 from server (123, "Material/a/resource")
Material 2 from server (234, "Material/b/resource")
Material 3 from server (123, "Material/a/resource")
```

Comment: you are correct for NEW_MATERIAL function, edit my question

Comment: Last edit was 5 hours ago. I don't see it. Also, please avoid editing the question in ways that invalidate existing answers

Comment: can I get explanation the difference between "template <class Arg1>" with "template <typename Arg1>?

Comment: Yeah, there's no difference. Just `typename` is more generic (it doesn't exclude "int", "double" or "struct X*"). It's a matter of taste really. [To get /very/ technical there WAS a difference only in the context of [template template arguments before c++17](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_parameters#Template_template_parameter), but let's not get side-tracked]

Comment: this accepted answer, especially "construct" function within class BOOST_OBJECT_POOL_CHECKER